# Kernel Module insertion failed due to kernel mismatch

Tags: kernel, filesystem, compiling, system

While inserting module xfs.ko it gave kernel mismatch error

I am trying to build linux kerenl version 5.15.1 on my Virtual Machine and trying to insert xfs.ko from it into the VM's kernel as a module. But my VM kernel version is 5.15.0(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) and I am unable to find the same version as my VM on kernel.org. It is giving kernel mismatch error.

Comment: You should install the kernel you compiled. Boot to it. Then load your module.